# How to rewrite the links in the error message of php

Tags: php

The **dev** environnement is split in 2 parts:

1. the IDE + the source (both on the developper laptop)
2. the remote server where the code is executed.

The 2 environnements have a different tree structure of files. Therefore the url displayed on the php error messages (fatal, warning, notice, etc) matches the server but not the laptop.

Is there a way to rewrite the links (replace the root) in the error messages of php? (This would allow to browse directly to the correct file on the laptop from an error message.)

Example of a rewritten link in some php error message:

Original is `/var/www/library/form/detail.php` (Matches the server)

Desired is `/home/project/www/library/form/detail.php` (Matches the laptop)

Notes:

- the rewriting rule is fixed: `/var/...` => `/home/project/...`
- this is only for a **dev** environnement.

Comment: hm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722850/rewrite-the-path-of-the-php-error-messages

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Please bare in mind, your reputation allows you to view questions which users have removed. I cannot view this link, so Toto definitely wont be able too

Comment: My previous question turned into a homogeneous/heterogeneous environnement debate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the start of your code:

```
ob_start(function($c) {
    return str_replace("/var/www/","/home/project/www/",$c);
});
```

This will cause any instance of `/var/www/` in your output to be replaced with `/home/project/www/`. This should be fine for dev purposes.

For actual deployment, you'd have proper error handling anyway, and in that you can log the error yourself through a proper error handling system, which can include the replacement above.

Comment: Interesting! Frustrating we can set the root of the documentation but not the file links in the error messages. http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.docref-root